# Force python2.7 setup.py install to python2.7 not python2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, package-management

I'm trying to install python packages to the python2.7 site-packages folder but it puts some of them in the python2.6 site-packages folder.

I've read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) and can't get my head round how to solve this. It's driving me nuts!

I've consistently been using python2.7 (`/usr/local/bin/python2.7 setup.py install`) to install different packages, and the logs for one say it's gone into `.../python2.6/site-packages` and others go into `.../python2.7/site-packages`

Please can someone straighten me out here?

Comment: Then run `setup.py` with Python 2.7, not Python 2.6. And what do you mean by *some* of the files?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's the thing, I have. And by some I mean neither all of one or the other

Comment: I was inviting you to tell us what files where ending up where.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [DjangoAngular](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pdb) ended up in ...2.7, [django-pdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pdb) in 2.6

Comment: So what command-line did you use to install those?

Comment: @martijn it's in my question: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 setup.py install

Comment: So for both packages, you unzipped the source tarball, and ran that command in each directory?

Comment: @MartijnPieters any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, haven't yet had time to do much spelunking.